# Passing a string to agedge in agraph.py. Issue with networkx and pygraphviz

Tags: python, c, swig, graphviz, networkx

Given this initial graph:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.MultiGraph()
fromnodes=[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,7,8,9,10]
tonodes=[1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
dupedgeind=0
for x,y in zip(fromnodes,tonodes):
    if G.has_edge(x,y):
        dupedgeind=dupedgeind+1
        G.add_edge(x,y,key=dupedgeind)
    else:
        dupedgeind=0
        G.add_edge(x,y,key=dupedgeind)
```

Can anyone recreate this error?

```
pos=nx.nx_agraph.pygraphviz_layout(G,prog='sfdp')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py", line 262, in pygraphviz_layout
    A=to_agraph(G)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py", line 155, in to_agraph
    A.add_edge(u,v,key=str(key),**str_edgedata)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 484, in add_edge
    eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, key, _Action.find)
KeyError: 'agedge: no key'
```

The problem has something to do with the call to graphviz's agedge function, it seems to not like the format of the `key` parameter; when I change (line 480 of `agraph.py`):

```
...
    eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, key , _Action.create)
...
```

to

```
...
    eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, "a_string" , _Action.create)
...
```

it no longer fails (but loses the key labels).

**Is there an obvious way to fix this** (so that `key` parameter values are retained)**?** - Nothing I try seems to work.

**What are the most sensible next debugging steps?**

---

From [here](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/cgraph.3.pdf), it appears that the `c` agedge function (which I can't see as it's in a .pyd binary) has the following format:

```
*agedge(Agraph_t *g, Agnode_t *t, Agnode_t *h, char *name, int createflag)
```

where the `char *name` is the key.

I cannot work out why it won't accept a `str` dtype as in the initial error.

---

Note versions:

networkx - 1.11,
pygraphviz - 1.3.1
 (installed from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz)
Python 2.7 (32bit - isntalled via python(x,y)) on Windows 7 (64-bit), GraphViz - 2.38

I have also seen this issue crop up in these questions:

- [Hierarchical graph with parallel edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979125/hierarchical-graph-with-parallel-edges)
- [How to draw parallel edges in Networkx / Graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007046/how-to-draw-parallel-edges-in-networkx-graphviz)

---

**UPDATE 1**

I have tried adjusting the `key` input to the agedge function to a number of variants of char arrays (e.g. `(ct.c_char_p * len(key))(key)` (ct is ctypes module) based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16700183/1461850)). This changes the error to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py", line 262, in pygraphviz_layout
    A=to_agraph(G)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py", line 155, in to_agraph
    A.add_edge(u,v,str(key),**str_edgedata)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 482, in add_edge
    eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, (ct.c_char_p * len(key))(key), _Action.create)
TypeError: in method 'agedge', argument 4 of type 'char *'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I can get it to run (but not return a multigraph) if I do this:

In `agraph.py` replacing the line

```
eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, key , _Action.create)
```

with

```
    try:
        # new
        if key==0:
            eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, str(0), _Action.create)
        else:
            eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, str(1), _Action.create)
```

I don't know why just casting to a string `str(key)` does not work.

**UPDATE 3 - EDIT with the function**

Found the function here - https://github.com/ellson/graphviz/blob/master/lib/cgraph/edge.c

```
Agedge_t *agedge(Agraph_t * g, Agnode_t * t, Agnode_t * h, char *name,
int cflag)
{
    Agedge_t *e;
    IDTYPE id;
    int have_id;
    have_id = agmapnametoid(g, AGEDGE, name, &id, FALSE);
    if (have_id || ((name == NILstr) && (NOT(cflag) || agisstrict(g)))) {
        /* probe for pre-existing edge */
        Agtag_t key;
        key = Tag;
        if (have_id) {
            key.id = id;
            key.objtype = AGEDGE;
        } else {
            key.id = key.objtype = 0;
        }
        /* might already exist locally */
        e = agfindedge_by_key(g, t, h, key);
        if ((e == NILedge) && agisundirected(g))
            e = agfindedge_by_key(g, h, t, key);
        if (e)
            return e;
        if (cflag) {
            e = agfindedge_by_key(agroot(g), t, h, key);
            if ((e == NILedge) && agisundirected(g))
                e = agfindedge_by_key(agroot(g), h, t, key);
            if (e) {
                subedge(g,e);
                return e;
            }
        }
}
```

**UPDATE 4:**

The source of the error is within [this](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/blob/245fc9507a9e40f8c35762dd5073e42edb0388d3/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c) pygraphviz file, graphviz_wrap.c, line 3921:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_agedge(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
    PyObject *resultobj = 0;
    Agraph_t *arg1 = (Agraph_t *) 0 ;
    Agnode_t *arg2 = (Agnode_t *) 0 ;
    Agnode_t *arg3 = (Agnode_t *) 0 ;
    char *arg4 = (char *) 0 ;
    int arg5 ;
    void *argp1 = 0 ;
    int res1 = 0 ;
    void *argp2 = 0 ;
    int res2 = 0 ;
    void *argp3 = 0 ;
    int res3 = 0 ;
    int res4 ;
    char *buf4 = 0 ;
    int alloc4 = 0 ;
    int val5 ;
    int ecode5 = 0 ;
    PyObject * obj0 = 0 ;
    PyObject * obj1 = 0 ;
    PyObject * obj2 = 0 ;
    PyObject * obj3 = 0 ;
    PyObject * obj4 = 0 ;
    Agedge_t *result = 0 ;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, char*)"OOOOO:agedge",&obj0,&obj1,&obj2,&obj3,&obj4)) SWIG_fail; 
    res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj0, &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_Agraph_t, 0 | 0 );
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {
        SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), "in method '""agedge" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "Agraph_t *""'");
    }
    arg1 = (Agraph_t *)(argp1);
    res2 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj1, &argp2,SWIGTYPE_p_Agnode_t, 0 | 0 );
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(res2)) {
        SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res2), "in method '" "agedge" "', argument " "2"" of type '" "Agnode_t *""'");
    }
    arg2 = (Agnode_t *)(argp2);
    res3 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj2, &argp3,SWIGTYPE_p_Agnode_t, 0 | 0 );
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(res3)) {
        SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res3), "in method '" "agedge" "', argument " "3"" of type '" "Agnode_t *""'");
    }
    arg3 = (Agnode_t *)(argp3);
    res4 = SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize(obj3, &buf4, NULL, &alloc4);
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(res4)) {
        SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res4), "in method '" "agedge" "', argument " "4"" of type '" "char *""'");
    }
    arg4 = (char *)(buf4);
    ecode5 = SWIG_AsVal_int(obj4, &val5);
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(ecode5)) {
        SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(ecode5), "in method '" "agedge" "', argument " "5"" of type '" "int""'");
    }
    arg5 = (int)(val5);
    {
        result = (Agedge_t *)agedge(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5);
        if (!result) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyError,"agedge: no key");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_Agedge_t, 0 | 0 );
    if (alloc4 == SWIG_NEWOBJ) free((char*)buf4);
    return resultobj;
    fail:
        if (alloc4 == SWIG_NEWOBJ) free((char*)buf4);
        return NULL;
}
```

Or, it's within [this one](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/blob/245fc9507a9e40f8c35762dd5073e42edb0388d3/pygraphviz/graphviz.i), graphviz.i, line 68.

Either way, it seems like the error string "agedge: no key" is returned if `agedge` fails for any reason... Perhaps it's something to do with SWIG.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, have you tried casting your key to a string: `G.add_edge(x,y,key=str(dupedgeind))`?

Comment: @MarkkuK. Thanks. Problem persists though.

Comment: How is this related to C?

Comment: @AshishAhuja Correct me if I'm wrong, but the Graphviz agedge function is written in C (see the [link](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/cgraph.3.pdf) in the qustion)

Comment: ^^ The link you've given in the comment isn't getting loaded. All other sites are working.

Comment: @atomh33ls, Can you just post the code of the `agedge` function in your question? Then I might be able to help, but not in the python part, as I don't know python.

Comment: @atomh33ls, Thanks, but just now the page also got loaded. I could not find the code of the function, do you have it? Right now you've posted the `declaration`. I mean that `agedge (what comes here)`

Comment: @AshishAhuja Think I've found it at the [Github source repository](https://github.com/ellson/graphviz/tree/master/lib) - edited question.

Comment: @atomh33ls, yes I see it. I'll get back to you when I get an answer.

Comment: @atomh33ls I believe that you have some weird environment problem. Your code works fine on my computer. I'm using `networkx==1.11`, `pygraphviz==1.3.1` and graphviz `2.38.0`. Did you try running your code in virtual environment?

Comment: I can also verify that the code works for me `networkx-1.11`, `pygraphviz-1.3.1` and `graphviz-2.38.0`.  My OS is Linux.  Perhaps something is miscompiled?

Comment: @atomh33ls Also you can try to get pygraphviz and other libraries  for windows here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz.

Comment: Did you try to encode your string to bytes?
`eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, key.encode('utf-8') , _Action.create)`

Comment: @CyrillePontvieux Thanks, tried that but it did not work.

Comment: @vsminkov Thanks, are you using windows? If so, 64 or 32 bit? I'm not (yet) familiar with virtual environments...

Comment: How about trying the "official CPython distribution" as recommended on http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz where you got the pygraphviz binaries from?

Comment: @Aric - thanks will do. However, I've only just noticed the "Chances are they do not work with custom Python distributions included with ... pythonxy..." [note](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) :-O

Comment: @Aric - also I've since switched to Ubuntu and it works fine. Will be a while before I check above (BIOS issues)..

Comment: @Aric Finally tried with the "official CPython distribution", not using Christoph Gohlke's binaries at all. I get the same error (on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the variable name from "key" to something else like "temp_key".  I mean that it is possible that you (or any previously imported module) has declared a non-string type "key" variable before...?

Apparently if running :

```
eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, key , _Action.create)
```

fails but running:

```
eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, "key" , _Action.create)
```

give you no issue, it could only be relative to the "key" variable type.. did you try this:

```
eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, str(key) , _Action.create)
```

or
`eh = gv.agedge(self.handle, uh, vh, unicode(key) , _Action.create)`

Integrate str()/unicode() in your orginal code give:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.MultiGraph()
fromnodes=[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,7,8,9,10]
tonodes=[1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
dupedgeind=0
for x,y in zip(fromnodes,tonodes):
    if G.has_edge(x,y):
        dupedgeind=dupedgeind+1
        G.add_edge(x,y,key=str(dupedgeind))
        #G.add_edge(x,y,key=unicode(dupedgeind))
    else:
        dupedgeind=0
        G.add_edge(x,y,key=str(dupedgeind))
        #G.add_edge(x,y,key=unicode(dupedgeind))
```

both (str & unicode version) works fine on Linux.

Best regards

Comment: Exact same error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007046/how-to-draw-parallel-edges-in-networkx-graphviz look like to be definitly relative to a Microsoft Windows package installation/compilation issue.

Comment: Thanks - I also put that link in the question. Can you expand on what the issue might be?

Comment: The issue looks like to be relative to variable "type" or variable "type conversion" error. Because if you put a real const string argument for key arg in your add_edge func there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:
set attribute `strict=False` on the graph.

```py
pygraphviz.AGraph(
  directed=True,
  strict=False,
)
```

This pygraphviz attribute is mentioned in the [`add_edge` method documentation](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/agraph.html#pygraphviz.AGraph.add_edge):

> The optional key argument allows assignment of a key to the edge. This is especially useful to distinguish between parallel edges in multi-edge graphs (strict=False).

The "agedge: no key" error message could not possibly be more misleading...